# UITableView scroll animation on reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

I'm trying to animate the content of a tableview right after my data are reloaded.
I succeed by doing this:

```
[_tableView reloadData];
[_tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-_tableView.contentSize.height, 0, 0, 0)];
[UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration animations:^{
    [_tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(35, 0, 0, 0)];
    [_tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f,-35.f)];
}];
```

But my animation has not the same speed on different content size (slower or faster).
How can adjust my speed and have exactly the same animation after each reload ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set animation duration in proportion to content size of your table view.

```
[_tableView reloadData];
[_tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-_tableView.contentSize.height, 0, 0, 0)];

animationDuration = _tableView.contentSize.height * aConstantK;

[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
    [_tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(35, 0, 0, 0)];
    [_tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f,-35.f)];
}];
```